# How can i add language to android system in settings?

Tags: android-emulator

I use Galaxy Tap7.7 Jelly Bean 4.1.1 and I already translate framework-res.apk and Settings.apk in res\values-km-rkh into khmer language(Cambodian Language) but in settings it only show the letter "khmer" in language list and i want it to show "ភាសាខ្មែរ" instead of "khmer" like this image [Khmer Language](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/923c5a07824ef0ac3de70b2b19e56749/5056f000/1/3/2/5/0/2/6/khmer.JPG). How should i do?

Thankss